# Can i install condenser unit of split air conditioner in a rotated position?

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning

I have to install a 1.5 ton split AC in my home. Due to some space constraints I can't install the condenser unit (the external unit) as instructed. Can I install it by rotating it by 90 degrees.

[image: The normal way of installing condenser unit.]

[image: The way I want to get it installed.]

I am asking if it will create any problem in working of AC?

Comment: Have you tried asking the manufacturer's technical support?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel hit it on the nose. All we could answer would be "Maybe", unless we checked the documentation, which I guarantee addresses exactly this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably not. The problem is there is a compressor in there and that uses gravity to keep the oil in the compressor. Have you ever heard that you need to let a refrigerator stand upright after moving it if it was laid on its side or back. This is to allow the oil time to drain back to the compressor. And usually takes 4 hours to 24 hours.
 If the unit is placed on its side it it will fail in a very short period of time, I do not know of any models that can allow to be run other than 1 position.